# QueryDSL Left Join not mapping properly with JPA entity

Tags: jpa, querydsl

QueryDSL is not working properly with JPA for left join.
I am using queryDSL version 4.2.1 and mapping the response directly to javax.persistence entity. 
For Left join/Right join, the joining condition it's not working. It fetches every entity disregarding the joining condition(here it's name = "testName") when `entity1.getEntity2()` is being called.

Is there any other way applicable for this case to map the result after `JOIN` tables ?

```
JPAQuery<Entity1> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
query.from(table1);
query.leftJoin(table2).on(table2.id.eq(table1.id).and(table2.name.eq("testName"));
List<Entity1> list = query.fetch();
```

```
@Entity
public class Entity1{

 private Integer id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<Entity2> entity2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An left or right join is an outer join.

So if you use left join all records from the left (in your case table1) will be selected.

If you only want records from table1 if there are corresponding records on table2 you have to use innerJoin.

```
JPAQuery<Entity1> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
query.from(table1);
query.innerJoin(table2).on(table2.id.eq(table1.id).and(table2.name.eq("testName"));
List<Entity1> list = query.fetch();
```

Read more about the join types here:

https://www.diffen.com/difference/Inner_Join_vs_Outer_Join

Comment: In the joining condition I have mentioned `table2.name.eq("testName")`. So, LEFT JOIN shouldn't fetch data from `table2` where name is not `testName`. 
But it's fetching every data whatever the name is !

Comment: Oh I see. That's not possible what you are trying because you have a relationship to Entity2 so all data is loaded into the entity.

Comment: Any other workaround to do this ? 
For example, mapping to queryDSL class, not JPA, like the mapping strategy of JOOQ.

Comment: It's not about the tool but about the fact that the collection is not filtered. You have to do two queries one for the Entity1 and then a second for the Entitiy2 collection